# FFMPEG in Java (runtime error)

Tags: java, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

I want to write a program that converts video into frames using FFMPEG. When I use it on the Ubuntu terminal, it works fine. But when I try to put it into the Java code, it gives me a runtime error. Did I make a mistake in my code below?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ConvertVideoToImage
{
    private SingletonServer ss = null;

    public ConvertVideoToImage(SingletonServer ss)
    {
        this.ss = ss;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        convertVideo();
    }

    public void convertVideo()
    {
        try
        {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRunTime().exec("ffmpeg" + "-i" +         "display.wmv" + "image%d.jpg");
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

I have changed the code like you suggested, but it also doesn't work. And when I Googled it, I found out that someone put the full path inside the executable and it became like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/pc3/Documents/ffmpeg_temp/ffmpeg -i display.wmv image%d.jpg")
```

BTW, thanks for the reply. I have another question. Is it possible to make a counter for FFMPEG? I used this command in the Ubuntu terminal to make it convert a video to 30 frames/1seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i display.wmv image%d.jpg
```

This will automatically generate numbers like image1.jpg, image2.jpg, to image901.jpg. Is it possible to make a counter for this? Because I need to count the files and control the number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also put here the error text (stacktrace)?

Comment: i have settle the error by using another code and replace the format .. btw , thanks  weekens@weekens

Answer (score 0):

When you call `exec`, you should not specify the parameters in the command string, instead, pass them in an array as second parameter.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRunTime().exec("ffmpeg",
               new String[]{"-i", "display.wmv", "image%d.jpg"));
//                        are you sure regarding this %^
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .

i have change the code like you suggest but i doesn't work also . and i google it, i found out that someone put the full path inside the exec and it becomd like this

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/pc3/Documents/ffmpeg_temp/ffmpeg -i display.wmv image%d.jpg")

it can compile without error. is there possible to use a counter to replace the image%d.jpg ? thanks in advance